# build desktop application that can open web pages and interact with their contents

Tags: desktop-application, webautomation

I need to build a desktop application with GUI that can

1. manage data and run database queries
2. open webpages and interact with their contents
3. login automatically to websites
4. fill web forms with data stored in the application
5. store contents of webpages
6. navigate through webpages

[prototype image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmFyx.png)

with taking in mind ...number of records will not exceeded 1000 per month, number of user will be less than 30 user

which programming language can I start with?

Answer (score -1):

By desktop application you mean that you want a graphic user interface?

You can definitely build simple interfaces with Python (e.g. [Tkinter](https://realpython.com/python-gui-tkinter/)). And Python has great packages for web automation (e.g. [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/)), but I am not sure what kind of database you want to interact with.

If the database can be accessed via an API, Python will work, too. In some cases, there are ready-made packages to handle specific APIs in Python, in other cases you can access them via [Requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/)

But more experienced users may have more advice on that front.

Comment: yes I want a graphic user interface, currently I'm using an access database

Comment: Here is a tutorial for connecting Python to Access: https://datatofish.com/how-to-connect-python-to-ms-access-database-using-pyodbc/